# Alert notification is not being removed when the user was logged out of the app

Tags: codenameone

We have an issue related to notifications removal of App. Using with performBackgroundFetch method notifications are coming fine, if user received the notification and then logged Out with Out reading the received notification then notification on notifications bar not being removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove this notification by calling [`Display.cancelLocalNotification()`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#cancelLocalNotification-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Can you please give me one example for it, we already calling Display.cancelLocalNotification() but it wasn't working while logout